# Nonblocking Scrapy pipeline to database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, scrapy, twisted, nonblocking

I have a web scraper in Scrapy that gets data items. I want to asynchronously insert them into a database as well.

For example, I have a transaction that inserts some items into my db using SQLAlchemy Core:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    with self.connection.begin() as conn:
        conn.execute(insert(table1).values(item['part1'])
        conn.execute(insert(table2).values(item['part2'])
```

I understand that it's possible to use SQLAlchemy Core asynchronously with Twisted with [`alchimia`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/alchimia). The documentation code example for `alchimia` is below.

What I don't understand is how can I use my above code in the alchimia framework. How can I set up `process_item` to use a reactor?

Can I do something like this?

```
@inlineCallbacks
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    with self.connection.begin() as conn:
        yield conn.execute(insert(table1).values(item['part1'])
        yield conn.execute(insert(table2).values(item['part2'])
```

**How do I write the reactor part?**

**Or is there an easier way to do nonblocking database insertions in a Scrapy pipeline?**

---

For reference, here is the code example from `alchimia`'s documentation:

```
from alchimia import TWISTED_STRATEGY

from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable

from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from twisted.internet.task import react


@inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor):
    engine = create_engine(
        "sqlite://", reactor=reactor, strategy=TWISTED_STRATEGY
    )

    metadata = MetaData()
    users = Table("users", metadata,
        Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True),
        Column("name", String()),
    )

    # Create the table
    yield engine.execute(CreateTable(users))

    # Insert some users
    yield engine.execute(users.insert().values(name="Jeremy Goodwin"))
    yield engine.execute(users.insert().values(name="Natalie Hurley"))
    yield engine.execute(users.insert().values(name="Dan Rydell"))
    yield engine.execute(users.insert().values(name="Casey McCall"))
    yield engine.execute(users.insert().values(name="Dana Whitaker"))

    result = yield engine.execute(users.select(users.c.name.startswith("D")))
    d_users = yield result.fetchall()
    # Print out the users
    for user in d_users:
        print "Username: %s" % user[users.c.name]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    react(main, [])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I set up process_item to use a reactor?

You don't need to manage another reactor in your pipeline.
Instead, you could do asynchronous database interactions within an item pipeline by returning a deferred from the pipeline.

See also [Scrapy's doc](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#process_item) and [sample code doing asynchronous operations within an item pipeline by returning a deferred](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#take-screenshot-of-item).