# How to pass several parameters in FEED_URI (Scrapy) Python

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, output

My question is simple - is there any way to pass several output sources for Scrapy? Like I want to save duplicate of scraped result into ftp. Should I create additional pipeline for this 
 purpose? Thank You!

Comment: [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html) mentions  only one item for `FEED_URI` and one for `FEED_FORMAT`. But I would send on FTP after getting all result and then you don't have to do it in scraper.

Comment: I made a new pipeline for this purposes and now I am able to save duplicates to ftp

Answer (score 1):

This is **not possible** at the moment. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1336) for it, and a [proposed implementation](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/3858) that *may* become available in the upcoming [Scrapy 2.0](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/milestone/10) version. Maybe you could try the proposal out and review it.

In the meantime, yes, item pipelines are one way to do it. But if you don’t want to slow down your crawl you need to [use deferreds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43979707/939364). The code in [open pull request #3961](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/3961) may help, but it is far from trivial, specially if you are not familiar with Twisted.

There’s also the option of uploading the file to FTP after the spider has finished generating the local file, which is probably the most straightforward solution until multiple-feed support is implemented.